# C - Read from input stream, tab as spaces

Tags: c, input, getchar, putchar

I'm a bit stuck and am hoping that someone can take a quick look to find what I'm doing wrong. I want to have the tabs count as spaces for output and not tabs. In this case, I'm using 3 spaces = 1 tab. I'm assuming that it may be something to do with how I set up my first while statement since right now it's reading tab as a tab.

```
int main()
{
  int i, c;
  int N = 3;

  while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n')
  putchar (c);
  while ((c = getchar()) == '\t')
  for (i=1; i<=N; i++) 
    {
      putchar(' ');
    }
  system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: Explain further what are you doing ? where do read input and where do you put the output ?

Comment: @3bdalla I'm just doing it in the terminal. Input is read from user input into the terminal and output shows up on the next line. Basically repeating itself unless there's a tab in which case, spaces should show up instead of a tab.

Comment: @Axalo Using a Windows partition right now on my Mac.

Comment: @Axalo Yes, Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    int i, c;
    int N = 3;

    // exit on Ctrl-C
    while((c = getch()) != 3)
    {
        if(c == '\t')
        {
            for(i=1; i<=N; i++)
            {
                putchar(' ');
            }
        }
        else if(c == '\r')
        {
            putchar('\r');
            putchar('\n');
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. Had to change a little bit around though. getch() should be getchar(), and !=EOF, not 3. Also not sure what '\r' is, though I didn't need that whole piece anyways.